# Adding credentials for MongoDb access issues

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following configuration file in my Spring application:

```
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(host, port), database);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());

        return mongoTemplate;

    }
}
```

Now all I want to do is to set up username/password for accessing the mongo database.

**The issue is ALL functions for passing credentials seem to be deprecated in mongo-java-driver 3.6.4**

I have tried this:

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray());
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient (new ServerAddress(host, port), Arrays.asList(credential));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipleMongoProperties.class)
public class MultipleMongoConfig {

    /** The mongo properties. */
    private final MultipleMongoProperties mongoProperties;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new multiple mongo config.
     *
     * @param mongoProperties the mongo properties
     */
    @Autowired
    public MultipleMongoConfig(MultipleMongoProperties mongoProperties) {
        super();
        this.mongoProperties = mongoProperties;
    }

    /**
     * Lab mongo template.
     *
     * @return the mongo template
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "labMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate labMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(labFactory(this.mongoProperties.getLab()));
    }

    /**
     * Historical mongo template.
     *
     * @return the mongo template
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Bean(name = "historicalMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate historicalMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(historicalFactory(this.mongoProperties.getHistorical()));
    }


    /**
     * Lab factory.
     *
     * @param mongo the mongo
     * @return the mongo db factory
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MongoDbFactory labFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {

        return getMongoDbFactory(mongo);
    }

    /**
     * Historical factory.
     *
     * @param mongo the mongo
     * @return the mongo db factory
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory historicalFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
        return getMongoDbFactory(mongo);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the mongo db factory.
     *
     * @param mongo the mongo
     * @return the mongo db factory
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private MongoDbFactory getMongoDbFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) {
        List<MongoCredential> credentials = Arrays.asList(
                MongoCredential.createCredential(mongo.getUsername(), mongo.getDatabase(), mongo.getPassword()));
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(
                new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()), credentials), mongo.getDatabase());
    }

}
```

Its fine, I guess, I have not faced any issues as of now. It is in production from like last 6 months.

Comment: The constructor MongoClient(ServerAddress, List<MongoCredential>) is deprecated. You must be using an older version